# setting a div to bottom with no collisions

Tags: css

I want to style a div in such a way that it will be at the bottom of the page if the page height is over 700px if not then set it to a position from top of 700px. This can be achived by jQuery but I wanted to know if you could do this with css. Kinda like a min from top sort of thing?

Comment: you may need to use JavaScript if you want to support IE 6 users, as IE 6 does not recognize `min-height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting min-height 700px on the content and then simply adding a position fixed to bottom footer?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking for a *sticky footer*.  There's a few sites that offer HTML + CSS sticky footer solutions with slightly differing techniques.

- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/
- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
- http://www.lwis.net/journal/2008/02/08/pure-css-sticky-footer/

The one I use is at http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/.